# I have a onclick button that moves a line up, how do I get the line to not move up after it hits a certain x,y value?

Tags: qt, qml

I draw a line by drawing a Rectangle of height 1. Then, I have an onclick Button that moves the line up by decreasing it's y value. How do I get the line to not move up after it hits a certain y value?

```
Item
{
   Rectangle
   {
       id: rectangle
       color:"#ef5350"
       y: 50
       width: parent.width
       height: 1
   }

   Button
   {
       anchors.centerIn: parent
       text: "Move line up"
       onClicked: rectangle.y-=10
   }

}
```

I want my line to not move above a specific y value.

Comment: Welcome to SO, @Jack. First of all you have to read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As for your question, you have to provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and clarify your question since it is absolutely unclear what are talking about. What line? Line of what? What is your _real target_? What do you what to archive?

Answer (score 1):

Use a property to manage your offset and bound it to a maximum/minimum:

```
Rectangle {
   property int offset: 0
   id: rectangle
   color: "#ef5350"
   y: 70 + Math.max(offset, -5 * 10) // Not more than 5 hits
   width: parent.width
   height: 1
}

Button {
   anchors.centerIn: parent
   text: "Move line up"
   onClicked: rectangle.offset-=10
}
```

You can also move the logic in the `onClicked` property:

```
onClicked: {
     if (rectangle.offset == -50)
         return
     rectangle.offset-=10
}
```